# ¿Existe alguna librería en C# para tener relojes y mediciones de tiempo?

Tags: c#

Sé que en C++ existían unas librerías y yo las uso en clase pero creo que en C# la cosa cambia. Lo que en realidad quiero hacer es realizar una función cada 5 segundos. ¿Me podéis decir una librería asi?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! la clase timer hace lo que vos queres.. no se necesitan librerias externas...

Answer (score 0):

Eso de pendende del ambiente del que estemos hablando, si bien la clase timer te puede servir solo te sera 100% usable en ambientes como windows forms o consolas, sin embargo para la web de nada te sera util sobre todo si tus intenciones son lanzar tareas en background.

Si el ambiente por el que preguntas es Web entonces te recomiendo que uses la libreria [Hangfire](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire/).

Comment: si fuera web, entonces no seria mas js u otra cosa? digo porque pregunto concretamente algo de c a c# ;).igual la pregunta es poco clara respecto a eso y por eso no la conteste...

Comment: cuando decia Web me referia ambiente como asp.net, asp.net core que son web pero server side y puede desarrollarse usando c#

Comment: Se agradece la respuesta.. en general tratamos que no pase esto, suponer escenarios o poner respuestas que puedan llevar a confusion ;) te pido que leas el [tour] y tambien [answer].